# What to assert when unit testing an update method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit.net

Supposed you want to check if your update method has properly updated and lets say that you updated all fields of your object, do you assert if all fields changed?

What if you have many fields, how would you check if all fields were updated? And if the answer is you shouldn't check all fields, how do you safe guard that all fields are updated by your method?

I am using xUnit.Net, btw.

Comment: I would normally assert on each field within the object. Assert.AreEqual("foo", something.Name, "Foos name is wrong after update");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not assert that all fields changed, you assert that each and every field has the expected value.  This may even include fields that are not expected to be updated: you may assert that their value is unchanged.

If you want to take a shortcut, you can simply compute the hashcode of the object and assert that the hashcode is the expected one, but there are lots of things that can go wrong there, (a field may have a wrong value and the hashcode may stil match,) and modifying the testing code each time a field is added to the updatable object is going to be troublesome, so I would recommend against such a shortcut.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just to confirm, I will have lots of assert in my assert section of the test. If I have 20 fields that changed, I will have 20 asserts? Can you confirm?

Comment: Well, yes.  Unless you would prefer to bunch them together with "&&" operators, like `assert a == 1 && b == 2;` which though would make it a bit difficult to figure out what went wrong when something goes wrong.